# Date picker Angular

Tags: angular

What would cause the bsDatePicker in angular 10 to render his container empty?

Browser HTML
http://prntscr.com/zvhi7g

`<bs-datepicker-container role="dialog" aria-label="calendar" class="bottom ng-tns-c104-1 ng-star-inserted" style="display: block; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(531px, 418px, 0px);"><!--bindings={}--></bs-datepicker-container>`

CODE HTML

`<input type="text" placeholder="datepicker" class="form-control" bsDatepicker>`

Note: The bsDaterangepicker work just fine so i dont think that the solutions to imports css files or BrowserAnimationModule will fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to use a default value and use local dateformat like this:

```
let date = new Date(dateValue).toLocaleDateString();
```

Otherwise you can use the material date-picker - within a mat-form-field:
I have made good experiences with it

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Custom calendar header</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker [calendarHeaderComponent]="exampleHeader"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

see a example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: I m trying to find what will cause this empty container rather than implementing other solution.